# returnとyield fromの同時使用について

Tags: python, python3

実行環境: Python 3.10.4

```py
>>> def pro(value):
...     if value == 5:
...         return ['Python']
...     else:
...         yield from range(value)
>>> pro(5)
<generator object pro at 0x000001F1E696AC70>
```

を実行するとジェネレータオブジェクトが返されます．内部で何が起こっているのですか．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield`式 (`yield`文も意味は同じ) があると Generatorsです。

- [6.2.9. Yield 式](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) / [7.7. yield 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement)
- https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators

この場合の returnは, `StopIteration` 送出の意味

```py
def fn(value):
    print('=> start generator')
    for n in range(value):
        yield n
    return '== 停止 =='

gen = fn(3)
for n in gen:
    print(n)
# => start generator
# 0
# 1
# 2

gen = fn(1)
print(next(gen))
# => start generator
# 0
print(next(gen))
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
# StopIteration: == 停止 ==
```

類似質問: [yieldとreturnを併用したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51410/)

yield fromは, サブジェネレータへの委譲です

```py
def subgen():
    yield 100
    yield from 'やあ'
    return

def fn(value):
    print('=> start generator')
    yield from subgen()
    return '== 停止 =='

for n in fn(100):
    print(n)

# => start generator
# 100
# や
# あ
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．示されたコードを実行してみましたが，subgenで定義されたreturnや，fnで定義されたreturn '==停止=='がなくてもコードは動作します．この場合のreturnはどういう意味がありますか．

Comment: Pythonでは returnなしで抜けた場合, `return` や `return None` と同じ動作です。Generatorでも同様に `StopIteration`送出するだけ。returnで何らかの値を指定した場合, (回答に示したように) StopIteration 表示させれば出てきます

Comment: `StopIteration`を表すため明示的に `return`記述したわけだけど, returnあるなしの違いは [検索すると](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+return+なし) 質問・回答でてきます